# how to design a has a relationship in oop (using php)

Tags: php, oop

I am really new in OOP, and not a good English talker, so if my question is dumb, I am sorry.
I thought I understand the oop but when I start codding with it, it works but does not feel right. 
the following code is my first try, I will ask my question after them. (I cut the database codes, but as I said the program works.)

// class.Post.inc

```
class Post {
    private $_db;
    private $_postId;
    private $_title;
    private $_creatorId;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_db = Database::getInstance ()->getConnection ();
    }

    public function getApost($postId = 0) {
        if($postId){
            /* get the post data from database(including user_id) and put them in the instance variables */
            $this->_postId = $row ['post_id'];
            $this->_title = $row ['title'];
            $this->_creatorId = $row ['user_id'];
        }
    }

    public function getCreator() {
        $creator = new User ();
        return $creator->getUserObject ( $this->_creatorId );
    }

    public function getPostId() {
        return $this->_postId;
    }

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->_title;
    }
}
```

//class.User.inc

```
class User {
    private $_db;
    private $_userId;
    private $_name;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_db = Database::getInstance ()->getConnection ();
    }

    public function getUserObject($userId = null) {
        if ($userId) {
            /* read data from database and put them in the instance variables */
            $this->_userId = $row ['user_id'];
            $this->_name = $row ['name'];

            return $this;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function getUserId() {
        return $this->_userId;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->_name;
    }
}
```

//index.php

```
spl_autoload_register ( function ($className) {
    require_once 'classes/class.' . $className . '.inc';
} );

$post = new Post ();
$post->getApost(1);
$creator = $post -> getCreator();
echo $post->getPostId () . '<br>';
echo $post->getTitle () . '<br>';
echo $creator->getName () . '<br>';
```

my questions:

1. post has a creator, do I design this relationship right?
2. what if I want to use join to select post and its creator together?
3. if I want to show a list of posts, should I define a new method in the post class or in the index page or define a new class for it? how?

Comment: Might better fit on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You have mistakes in your code. 1) You  need to pass connection in as DI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection. 2) `getUserObject`, `getApost` is executive `new User(userId)`, `new Post(postId)` should return proper class instance. Also check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is much that can be said about your code. I could write what you did wrong few hours, but you didn't asked for that, so I answer your questions firsts.

1. Yes, it's ok to get creator from post from the perspective of entity relations.
2. I don't see any clean way using your implementation. It's possible, but it would require major refactoring.
3. If you want to use [Active Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) pattern, you could of course implement new method in Post class. But I much more recommend using [Data Mapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapper_pattern) pattern which is cleaner from OOP perspective because of [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

One piece of advice at the end:
I often see new developers to reinvent a wheel, which is exactly what you are doing. There are great and feature complete libraries which saves you lot of time writing your own. For example [Doctrine ORM](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/). Or much simplier [Nextras ORM](https://nextras.org/orm/docs/2.2/). Learning curve may seem high, but I guarantee, it's worth it.